# Azure Data Factory Compress Several Files to one single zip file

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Currently, we are working on a project that needs compress several files from Azure Blob.

For example,

```
ParentFolder
   File1
   File2
   ChildFolder
       File3
       File4
```

and the result we want is

```
ParentFolder.zip
```

Now, we noticed that Azure Data Factory can copy the data and compress it. But no matter what setting we chose, the best result we can get is to get all the file compressed seperately. And the compression type does not contain zip.

Like:

```
ParentFolder
     File1.gz
     File2.gz
     SubFolder
        File3.gz
        File4.gz
```

Is there any way to compress only the parent folder? Or is there any other service that we can give it a try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using the GZip compression type, so that all files are compressed as *.gz. Please use the ZipDeflate compression type instead. Refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs#compression-support.

Comment: You are right. I was not able to set the ZipDeflate before since I set the copy behavior of my sink to Preserved Hierarchy. After changed back to None, everything works. Thanks.